# how to close one stage and open another?

Tags: button, javafx

I have a stage I have filled with content. Now I want to close / hide that stage. I read that close / hide were equivalent, so I dont know which to use. After closing the stage I will open a new class and make a new stage, if there is a easy way to send the old stage to the new class and switch content I could use that solution as well.

I think "primaryStage" is hidden in "start" and cant be reached from "handle", and that is why is causing the problem, but I dont know the solution.

```
public class Main extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    Button btn1, btn2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        primaryStage.setTitle("title");

        btn1 = new Button("new");
        btn2 = new Button ("continue");

        btn1.setOnAction(this);
        btn2.setOnAction(this);

        VBox vb = new VBox (btn1, btn2);
        vb.setSpacing(10);
        vb.setPadding(new Insets(20));


        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setBottom(vb);

        Scene scene = new Scene (root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        if (event.getSource()==btn1) {
            // primaryStage.hide();
            NewClassWithStage newStage = new NewClassWithStage();

        }else if (event.getSource()==btn2) {
            // primaryStage.close();
            NewClassWithStage newStage = new NewClassWithStage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hidden? If you mean it's not in a surrounding scope then yes. You'd need to declare a field. Furthermore since both `close` and `hide` do the same thing, you can choose any of those 2.

Comment: Yes, I get primaryStage cannot be resolved. Am I supposed to declare it in main?

Comment: No, a field not a local variable is needed.

Answer (score 0):

So I wouldn't `implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>`  it makes everything more complicated you should try something like this see how you can still control the `primaryStage` if your in the start function still

```
public class Main extends Application {

    Button btn1, btn2;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("title");

        btn1 = new Button("new");
        btn2 = new Button ("continue");

        btn1.setOnAction(event -> {
            primaryStage.hide();
            NewClassWithStage newStage = new NewClassWithStage();
        });
        btn2.setOnAction(event -> {
            primaryStage.show();
            NewClassWithStage newStage = new NewClassWithStage();
        });

        VBox vb = new VBox (btn1, btn2);
        vb.setSpacing(10);
        vb.setPadding(new Insets(20));


        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setBottom(vb);

        Scene scene = new Scene (root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

}
```